# Lists and simplification rules: More difficult when using @ rather than #?

Tags: isabelle

While working through exercises in the Isabelle tutorials, I encountered a situation that confuses me. Why is it that the below lemma involving prepending to a list is proved so easily:

```
lemma ‹count_list xs x = n ⟹ count_list (x # xs) x = Suc n›
  by simp
```

While this one involving appending is not?

```
lemma ‹count_list xs x = n ⟹ count_list (xs @ [x]) x = Suc n›
  apply auto (* just does some minor rewriting *)
  (* What should be go here? try/try0 are of no help. *)
  done
```

I assume this has something to do with how the implementation of `@` is more involved than `#` due to the internal implementation of lists (`#` is just another constructor while `@` involves recursion), but what makes it so much more difficult to prove with and how do you account for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the ‘implementation’ of `@`. It has something to do with the ‘implementation’ of `count_list` (but I would say ‘definition’ rather than ‘implementation’).

Like most functions on lists, `count_list` is defined recursively (using the `primrec` command), which generates rules called `count_list.simps` that are added to the simpset (the set of rules that the simplifier uses for rewriting automatically).

If you type in `thm count_list.simps`, you will probably get something like this:

```
count_list [] ?y = 0
count_list (?x # ?xs) ?y = 
  (if ?x = ?y then count_list ?xs ?y + 1 else count_list ?xs ?y)
```

Since they are in the simpset, the simplifier that is invoked as a part of `auto` will always rewrite any instance of the left-hand side to the right-hand side.

Therefore, the first theorem you gave can be proven by a single step of rewriting with the second of these two rules and some more simplification. On that note, an equivalent and more usable formulation of that theorem would be `count_list (x # xs) x = Suc (count_list xs x)`.

Similarly, I would very much suggest to reformulate your second lemma as `count_list (xs @ [x]) x = Suc (count_list xs x)`.

Now why does `auto` not solve this? First of all, for this kind of goal, the only relevant part of `auto` for this kind of goal is the simplifier, so you might as well have written `simp_all` here. And the reason why that cannot solve the goal is that there it has no simplification rule for something like `count_list (… @ …)`. You will have to prove this yourself.

When you want to prove a property of a recursively-defined function, the usual approach is to do an induction that mirrors the recursive definition:

```
lemma ‹count_list (xs @ [x]) x = Suc (count_list xs x)›
  apply (induction xs)
  apply simp_all
  done
```

Or more compactly:

```
lemma ‹count_list (xs @ [x]) x = Suc (count_list xs x)›
  by (induction xs) simp_all
```

But I would actually recommend the following more general lemma:

```
lemma ‹count_list (xs @ ys) x = count_list xs x + count_list ys x›
  by (induction xs) simp_all
```

In fact, it is reasonable to give this fact a name and add it to the simp set as it makes a good rewrite rule:

```
lemma count_list_append [simp]:
    ‹count_list (xs @ ys) x = count_list xs x + count_list ys x›
  by (induction xs) simp_all
```

In case you're wondering why I did induction on `xs` here and not on `ys`: since the recursive definition of `count_list` pattern-matches on the first list element and the remaining list, one must do induction on the first list (i.e. `xs`) so that the induction step talks about `(x # xs) @ ys`, which simplifies to `x # (xs @ ys)` and then one can apply the induction hypothesis.

Note that `simp_all` (or `auto`) were sufficient to prove the induction goals in the above proof; once you tell Isabelle to do induction and what kind of induction, the rest of the proof is again just simple rewriting.